# What happens with fragments in back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

Say we use one or several `Activity`s with several `Fragment`s, add them to `BackStack`. For instance,

```
fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
?.replace(R.id.container, fragment, TAG)
?.addToBackStack(null)
?.commit()
```

After adding 3-5 fragments we then try to return back. Do these fragments save their states and restore (with recreate)? Or are they kept in memory, so that after adding 100 fragments we will receive `OOM` exception?

I am interested in this problem because use `Kotlin Android extensions`. When I turn off a screen, `onStop()` is called forcing fragments in `BackStack` to call `onSaveInstanceState()` event. In this case if I use

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putString(ARG_NAME, editText.text.toString())
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

I will get an `NPE` exception on `editText.text`, because `editText` is `null` for underlying fragments. Maybe I am not binding right, maybe it's a problem of Kotlin Android extensions.

Comment: You don't add fragments to backstack. You add transactions to backstack. What happens to them depends on what operator you use.

Comment: you won't get OOM exception because replace method show only one fragment at a time, If you use add instead of replace then you will get OOM exception because add method put new fragment to just above to previous one means both fragment show but one above other.

Comment: @RahulPareta, agree with you that both fragments are visible (and even can interact with clicks) when using `add`. I faced this situation and forgot about it.